# Regex with Unicode from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, xregexp

I'm in the process of porting some php code I have to nodejs.
The issue I have concerns this PCRE regex:

`/\/?_?[0-9]*_?([^\/\._]*)[_#*\-*\.?\p{L}\p{M}*]*$/u`

(this regex matches `first` in `_4_first_ääää`,in `_first_äääää` or `first_äääää`)

I'm using XRegExp in this context, but with no luck:

```
// lib/parser.js
var XRegExp = require('xregexp').XRegExp;

module.exports = { 
  getName : function(string){
    var name = XRegExp('\/?_?[0-9]*_?([^\/\._]*)[_#*\-*\.?\p{L}\p{M}*]*$');
    var matches = XRegExp.exec(string, name);
    if(matches && matches.length > 0){
      return matches[1];
    }
    else{
      return '';
    }
  }
};
```

And the test (mocha) that goes with it:

```
// test/test.js
var assert = require("assert");
var parser = require('../lib/parser.js');
describe('parser', function(){
  describe('#getName()', function(){
    it('should return the name contained in the string', function(){
      assert.equal('test', parser.getName('3_test'));
      assert.equal('test', parser.getName('test'));
      assert.equal('test', parser.getName('_3_test'));
      assert.equal('test', parser.getName('_3_test_ääää'));
      assert.equal('test', parser.getName('_3_test_boom'));
    })
  })
})
```

And the tests results:

```
0 passing (5ms)
1 failing

1) parser #getName() should return the name contained in the string:

  AssertionError: "test" == "ääää"
  + expected - actual

  +ääää
  -test
```

<strike>This code matches `ääää`.</strike>
<strike>The commented line catches `first` so I guess I'm missusing the unicodes caracter classes.</strike>

**My question is: how can I make my original php regex work in javascript?**

*Mmaybe there is a work around?*

Comment: there's no such thing as "php regex". You probably mean a `perl compatible regular expression` (or `preg`). I must admit I'm not at all familiair with XRegExp, so can't really help you with that. You'd need to look up the differences in parsing between the two.

Comment: @tularis - usually people follow up unnecessary clarifications with something useful.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know XRegExp, so I could be wrong. But you seem to be missing the delimiters in your first statement: `XRegExp('\`. You probably want something like `XRegExp('@/?_?...*$@')` instead.

Comment: @Tularis You're right, sorry for the confusion. I've been searching the XregExp website for answers in parallel http://xregexp.com/syntax/#unicode, it seems to be supported

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks but it seems XregExp doesn't need them: http://xregexp.com/syntax/

Comment: Are you loading the [Unicode add-ons](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode)

Comment: @Anthony it seems that this is just for browsers: http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode. In nodejs, if I understood correctly, it's all included, the same way it is in `xregexp-all.js`

Comment: Would it be a serious undertaking to add the one line of code to confirm?

Comment: @Anthony In the module documentation the author states that it is for browsers only https://www.npmjs.org/package/xregexp. So I assume it's all in there for the nodejs module. Maybe you have an idea on how to anyway specifically add it in node? I have no way to look at the module code at the moment, to make sure it's there

Comment: The answer to your problem lies, already answered, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode).

Comment: @tenub I've checked this thread, that's how I ended up using XregExp instead of `match()` Maybe you're pointing at something else in particular?

Comment: @m.pons Javascript does not support unicode character classes.  http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_cset might help in devising the equivalent in javascript

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks a lot for the link, if I don't manage to make it work the original way, I'll definitely turn to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find the origin of the problem. The \p{L} and \p{M} need another backslash in the Xregexp syntax. That change made the original regex work again.

```
var unicodeWord = XRegExp('^\\p{L}+$');
unicodeWord.test('Русский'); // -> true
unicodeWord.test('日本語'); // -> true
unicodeWord.test('العربية'); // -> true
```

from the usage examples: 
https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/README.md#usage-examples

Answer (score 0):

Put an anchor at the begining:

```
^\/?_?[0-9]*_?([^\/\._]*)[_#*\-*\.?\p{L}\p{M}*]*$
```

Also you could remove the unnecessary escaping:

```
^/?_?[0-9]*_?([^/._]*)[-_#*.?\p{L}\p{M}]*$
```

Your regex matches also an empty string, may be you want:

```
^/?_?[0-9]*_?([^/._]+)[-_#*.?\p{L}\p{M}]+$
```

According to your sample, id could be:

```
^/?(?:(?:_\d+)?_)?([^/._]+)[-_#*.?\p{L}\p{M}]+$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try it as soon as I'm not on mobile

Comment: Thanks for improving my query, unfortunately when I switch my regex with one of these, I get a null `matches` variable. Just the fact of adding the `^` at the beginning gives me a null `matches`...?!

Comment: @m.pons:It's certainly because you have some others character before. Could you show a real string that you have to check?